# Accessing post list from different block

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

Hi there,

I'm trying to implement a slider on the Wordpress (fishpig) homepage. I've created a new phtml template and added a slider block in the xml file. So far so good, markup gets rendered to the homepage where I want it to.

But the loop doesn't run, obviously because

```
$this->getPosts()
```

is referencing a different class than the Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_list.

My question is how can I access the post list from within the core/template slider block? I'm totally new to Magento so I'm just starting to wrap my head around the concept of blocks and how the whole templating system works.

I've tried

```
$className = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_list');
$block = new $className();
$block->getPosts();
```

and

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Post_list')->getPosts();
```

but to no avail. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include your new block and template in the XML, change the block type to "wordpress/sidebar_widget_posts". This will allow you to use the getPosts() method.

Alternatively, you could build your own collection of posts directly in your template:

```
<?php $posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->setOrderByPostDate()
    ->load() ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've gone with your second solution. Just a note: I got an error that addIsViewableFilter() method is undefined. I couldn't immediately find a similar method in the model files so I just left it out for now.